# Can Arduino w/ specific ethernet shield listen an ethernet port to collect datas

Tags: sockets, arduino, port, ethernet, tcp

I have an Arduino Duemilanove w/ Atmega328. I want to communicate with Arduino via local ethernet. I found 10$ [ENC28J60 Ethernet modules](http://hwstartup.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/ethernetmodule1.jpg) on eBay. Firstly, I tried [simple webserver example](http://hwstartup.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/how-to-connect-an-arduino-to-the-internet-for-10/) and it works. I know it's local IP address and I can communicate with Arduino with using my browser.

But, I do not want to use webserver. Is there any chance to listen directly a port. For example, I am sending datas to "192.168.2.5:8888" while Arduino has "192.168.2.5" as a local IP address. Which code simple I have to use in my Arduino to listen an ethernet port directly?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use other Ethernet interface chips to talk to an Arduino, but if you don't use one that's compatible with the chip on the Ethernet Shield, you might have to write your own library for it. I didn't find any information on that chip by using Google, so you'd have to post documentation to get any more detailed advice.

The Web examples are just easy to show new programmers. You would just go into the sketch and replace the Web server code with your own communication code, and you'll have to design your protocol like if you were using sockets with any system.

Comment: I added a documentation link in my question to get more detailed advices.

Comment: The link you posted is to a Google Docs attempt at rendering it. Please update the link to point directly to the PDF.

Comment: The HR91110A is just the jack, and you won't be talking to it directly. You'll need to use the documentation for the Ethernet controller chip you're using.

Comment: Question is edited second time and I think it has enough information now.